# How to find current active tab details in firefox from the command line?

Tags: firefox

I know a lot of information are available in

```
sessionstore.js
```

or

```
recovery.js
```

in later versions. But these information can be up to a minute outdated. Any way we can more current information about current tabs ?

changing

```
Browser.sessionstore.interval
```

is not an option.

Looking for url, title.

Comment: Find what information (title?, URL?) from where (Firefox add-on you're writing, other piece of software outside of the Firefox process)?

Comment: @nmaier from the command line. Sorry did not clarify. Yes, url, title.  Same information you find in recovery.js.